# How to write jquery function to custom element?

Tags: jquery

I wonder a small subject. Suppose I have a array that sample;

[image]

I have a hidden element:

```
<input type="hidden" name="sample" value="en" />
```

and I access objects on this way :

```
var sample = $('input[name="sample"]').val();
words.test[sample];
```

and Finally my curiosity is can I write custom event to `words element items` like this:

```
$(words.elements).on('selected',function(){
var sample = $('input[name="sample"]').val();
alert(this[sample]);
});
```

Comment: Instead of posting an image, please post it in text form. It will be much easier for people to copy/paste and test.

Comment: what is `words.elements`?

Comment: Can you please explain the problem you're trying to solve by doing this? This isn't something you can do with jQuery, but there are other things you *can* do, such as listen for a `<select>` with `onchange`.